# how to make worklight server for android app

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-studio

I created an android app in worklight with HTTP Adapter in Eclipse Juno,  I want to publish to publish it, I used API on server say 192.168.1.14, what should I write instead of Localhost, how to make new server to make app live. cannot understand IBM documentation to create the server. I want a simple way to create the server or any link with stepwise what to do.

- What server I need jsp or other pages.
- Can I test that server locally    like in Netbeans  before publishing?

Answer (score 1):

You develop your applications and adapters in MobileFirst Studio as you've done.

However, in order to serve your application to end users, **you must purchase a license from IBM**. Once you've done that you get access to download required files. When you have the files, the docs will make sense to you.

Ask your company to contact IBM.